# Вывод None вместе с простыми числами в классе- итераторе Primes

Tags: python, классы

Задача: класс- итератор. Принимает максимальное число N. Возвращает все простые числа от 1 до N.

При выводе я получаю простое число (если оно им является) и None если число не простое.
Хочу понять, почему так происходит, где ошибка и как поправить

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Код:

```
class Primes:
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.num = 0
        self.limit = limit

    def __isprime(self, n):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return n == 2
        d = 3
        while d * d <= n and n % d != 0:
            d += 2
        return d * d > n

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.num < self.limit:
            check = self.num
            self.num += 1
            if self.__isprime(check):
                return check
        else:
            raise StopIteration


mi = Primes(50)
for i in mi:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При каждом входе в метод `__next__(self)` ваша функция делает одну проверку, и чего-то да возвращает. Либо очередное число `check`, если оно простое. Либо ничего, т.е. по-сути `None`.
Наверное следует не выходить из функции, если число не простое, а перейти к следующему числу, проверить его, и т.д.

Т.е. просто замените `if self.num < self.limit:` на `while self.num < self.limit:`. Ну и строчку с `else:` уберите, с подвижкой `raise StopIteration` влево (хотя это и не обязательно *(имею ввиду убирание else)*).